# generic::invalid_argument: invalid build: invalid image name "us.gcr.io/.../... could not parse reference: us.gcr.io/..../

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, containers

I'm trying to deploy a container automatically when I push to github, I enabled the functionality on GCP but it didn't work and it complains when triggered that :

```
generic::invalid_argument: invalid build: invalid image name "us.gcr.io/cifar-clf/CIFAR-10_classification/cifar-clf:f2d5c55fad600b733fc5bcc84550fdd9a325b05b": could not parse reference: us.gcr.io/cifar-clf/CIFAR-10_classification/cifar-clf:f2d5c55fad600b733fc5bcc84550fdd9a325b05b
```

Dockerfile(in the root of the project):

```
FROM python:3.8

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

COPY . ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8080

CMD python app.py
```

but I got the error above.

For the ordinal deployement it works just fine using:

- To submit a build using Google Cloud Build

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/cifar-clf/cifar-clf --project=cifar-clf
```

- To deploy the container

```
gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/cifar-clf/cifar-clf --platform managed --project=cifar-clf --allow-unauthenticated
```

Any help or advice will be appreciated, Thanks folks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The named component of the image reference only allows for lowercase characters [from the distribution implementation](https://github.com/distribution/distribution/blob/32c77af6ac94ba4e34fc9aaa784c6ca69c114cf0/reference/regexp.go#L8):

```
// alphaNumericRegexp defines the alpha numeric atom, typically a
// component of names. This only allows lower case characters and digits.
alphaNumericRegexp = match(`[a-z0-9]+`)

// separatorRegexp defines the separators allowed to be embedded in name
// components. This allow one period, one or two underscore and multiple
// dashes. Repeated dashes and underscores are intentionally treated
// differently. In order to support valid hostnames as name components,
// supporting repeated dash was added. Additionally double underscore is
// now allowed as a separator to loosen the restriction for previously
// supported names.
separatorRegexp = match(`(?:[._]|__|[-]*)`)

// nameComponentRegexp restricts registry path component names to start
// with at least one letter or number, with following parts able to be
// separated by one period, one or two underscore and multiple dashes.
nameComponentRegexp = expression(
    alphaNumericRegexp,
    optional(repeated(separatorRegexp, alphaNumericRegexp)))
```

So you should change:

```
us.gcr.io/cifar-clf/CIFAR-10_classification/cifar-clf:f2d5c55fad600b733fc5bcc84550fdd9a325b05b
```

to:

```
us.gcr.io/cifar-clf/cifar-10_classification/cifar-clf:f2d5c55fad600b733fc5bcc84550fdd9a325b05b
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, The build was successful but didn't get pushed to GCP (No changes to the online application), Should I add something to configure it to push after build ? Thanks in advance man !

Comment: @mhannani I'm not familiar with gcloud based builds. In docker, you would do a `docker push`.

Answer (score 3):

The following approach will help you fix the error you are facing.

The same error occurred to me while deploying through `cloudbuild.yaml` using Build Triggers.
[image]

You can override the value of your reponame using the variable `$REPO_NAME` as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values)

To resolve the error you got like I did,

- Edit the Trigger
- add the variable REPO_NAME and override the repo name with `cifar-10_classification`

[image: P]

The credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/users/596285/bmitch for finding the root cause, as I stumble upon bmitch's root cause explanantion while doing [this POC](https://youtu.be/5M9yzZOJXaQ?t=2004).

Answer (score 0):

If your repo name contains upper case characters, directly using $REPO_NAME on cloud build as part of the Artifact registry repository name will cause an issue due to the artifact registry component's name validation. Only lowercase characters are acceptable.